# Should I use a smaller image as a thumbnail when using lightbox or just resize the image for it?

Tags: html, image

I'm using lightbox for a website. Would it have faster load times if I use a photoshop resized image for the thumbnail or would it be faster if I used the full resolution image but resized in html? It seems like a basic question but I haven't found the answer online anywhere.

Comment: Use a thumbnail for the initial load, then if the user wants to view the image on a larger scale then load the full image.

Comment: I'm using the full image in an <a> tag for lightbox and the thumbnail in an <img> tag nested in the <a>. Will the full image be loaded initially or only when it displays when the user clicks the thumbnail?

Comment: Press F12 and switch to the network tab, there you can see it.

Comment: I missed the line regarding lightbox, looking at that I'd say it depends on the size of your images, you obviously don't want to be loading images that are 10mb each for a website used mainly on mobiles. I'd recommend slight compression so the images still look good on a 24inch 1080p screen, but no bigger as its just wasted.  With lightbox you just link directly to the file.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I've solved the issue.

Comment: With what Legends said, remember that not everyone has a fantastic internet connection still, so if they load stupidly quick for you, they may not for someone else.